How to make a generated object available to a function generated inside another function
I need to call a function inside another function, as shown below. The original case is more complicated but this example is enough to illustrate the problem.
The function f is the function I need to write, which will call another function, j. j will call h to generate a function and then call it. g is the function to used inside h. Both j and h are fucntions in another package and I cannot change them. Due to the interface of j, I can only pass the function by name, "g" below.
f <- function() {
    g <- function() {
        10
      }
    j(g_name = "g")
  }

j <- function(g_name) {
    out <- h(g_name = g_name)
    cat("The body of `out`\n")
    print(body(out))
    cat("Call out:\n")
    out()
  }

h <- function(g_name) {
    out <- function() NULL
    body_str <- paste0(g_name, "()")
    body(out) <- parse(file = "",
                       text = body_str)
    out
  }

z <- f()
#> The body of `out`
#> g()
#> Call out:
#> Error in g(): could not find function "g"

Created on 2024-05-22 with reprex v2.1.0
As shown above, the body of the function generated by h inside j is indeed g(). However, an error occurred when calling out because g is not in the enclosing environment of out, even though it is in the environment when calling j inside f.
How can I make g available inside j, given that I cannot change j and h? I know one solution is to assign g to the global environment but I need to avoid messing with the global environment when f is running.

1) environments Add the line marked ## at the end so that j and h will look into f for functions and variables that they do not themselves define.
f <- function() {
    g <- function() {
        10
      }
    environment(j) <- environment(h) <- environment() ##
    j(g_name = "g")
  }

z <- f()
## The body of `out`
## g()
## Call out:
z
## [1] 10

2) attach Alternately attach g to the search path.
f <- function() {
    on.exit(detach(g)) ##
    g <- function() {
        10
      }
    attach(list(g = g), name = "g") ##
    j(g_name = "g")
  }

3) Crawl call stack Assume that h and j are in mypkg and j is exported but h is not.  Then this inserts code into h looks up the call stack to find g.  If h is exported use :: in place of :::
library(mypkg)
f <- function() {
  on.exit(quote(untrace(mypkg:::h))) ##
  trace(mypkg:::h, quote(g <- Find(\(e) "g" %in% ls(e), sys.frames(), TRUE)$g)) ##
  g <- function() {
      10
    }
  j(g_name = "g")
}
f()

4) Proxy environment Put h, j and g in a proxy environment e whose parent environment is the environment of mypkg::h.  Use :: in place of ::: if h is exported.
library(mypkg)

f <- function() {
  e <- new.env(parent = environment(mypkg:::h)) ##
  e$j <- j ##
  e$h <- mypkg:::h ##
  e$g <- g ##
  environment(e$j) <- environment(e$h) <- e ##
  g <- function() {
      10
    }
  e$j(g_name = "g")
}
f()

5) proto This is similar to (4) except it uses the proto package to shorten the code. a proto object is an environment with certain modified methods.  In particular inserting a function into a proto object changes the function's environment to be that object.  Also note that $.proto is redefined from $,environment so do not use p$j in the last line of f.
library(mypkg)
library(proto)

f <- function() {
  p <- proto(environment(mypkg:::h), j = j, h = mypkg:::h, g = g) ##
  g <- function() {
      10
    }
  with(p, j)(g_name = "g") ##
}
f()

Updates
Several alternatives and fixes added.

Thanks a lot. This indeed works for the example I posted becauae j() and h() are not really from a package. Unfortunately, in my case, j() and h() are in another package and I cannot easily write a reproducible example using the actual functions from those package. Moreover, h() is a function not exported and that's why I need to call j(). If I added environment(j) <- environment(), using the actual function from that package, I got this error: Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called '*tmp*

I found (2) right after I posted the comment. I tried (2) and it works for me when I used the actual function from the package! Many many thanks!

Sorry for asking one more question. Should detach() be included in (2), as in the original version? This solution changes the search path and may cause problems to other functions.

Thanks. I overlooked the on.exit(detach(g)) line.

I had originally put it in (1) by mistake and fixed it after I noticed my mistake.

Have added (3), (4) and (5).

While it does bog down the .globalenv, the <<- operator is a convenient shorthand. You can just delete the g when you're done, with rm(g, envir=.GlobalEnv). <<- is often a poor man's solution to scoping and is a great debug tool as well. You can't do this if g exists in the .GlobalEnv and you want to keep it - but though scoping can be done this way, I find it's a poor programming practice and likely to cause downstream problems that are harder to debug and harder to resolve. Avoiding naming conflicts with the .GlobalEnv will save your bacon
f <- function() {
  g <<- function() {
    10
  }
  val <- j(g_name = "g")
  rm(g, envir=.GlobalEnv)
  return(val)
}

j <- function(g_name) {
  out <- h(g_name = g_name)
  cat("The body of `out`\n")
  print(body(out))
  cat("Call out:\n")
  out()
}

h <- function(g_name) {
  out <- function() NULL
  body_str <- paste0(g_name, "()")
  body(out) <- parse(file = "",
                     text = body_str)
  out
}

z <- f()
z

Gives:
> z
[1] 10

PS: Just an example of how R causes scope hell, I had a dataset called ata with a variable called ata. I needed to merge baseline values to subject records, but the call ata$blata <- with(subset(ata, bl), ata[match(ata$id, id)]) could not resolve - I had to rename the variable to atan. Intuitively, we expect R to search an ever-broadening scope to find a version of ata for which ata$ is defined, but instead R has looked at the top scope only, found an ata there, and punished you for not doing exactly what it expects that version to do.
ata <- data.frame(
  bl = c(T, F, F, T, F, F),
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  ata = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
 )


I would like to avoid adding anything to the global environment. However, if this is the only feasible solution, I may need to give it a try, by using a name not conflicting with existing objects in the global environment.

@sfcheung Just keep your goal in mind. If I write a function, I don't assume the environment it will be used in. That way, Groethendik's answer is def. the "right" answer and quite elegant, but I can't imagine creating a function f intended to be used in g in h. Rather, I use something like minmax that could be inside tapply, or by, or aggregate - if the parameters to minmax (say I add Digits for rounding), it most often belongs in .GlobalEnv even if it makes your workspace ugly.

@sfcheung In fact, if you peruse R code for complicated algorithms like glm.fit for instance, if in fact you define a function f intended to be used in g intended to be used in h, each will respectively be defined inside of the scope of that function, so while the overall line count of the parent function is quite long, it doesn't cost much flop time, spares documentation, and still it organizes the approach to the source code.

Thanks a lot for your advice. I will take a look at those functions to find a better approach to solve my problem.

I found another solution to my question and I would like to share it here. My problem is due to the need to have the temporary dynamically generated function, g(), to be placed in the global environment for j() to work, but j() is actually from a package I use and I cannot change it. I've just found there is a package, callr, which can create an R session and do things there.  These are the steps of this solution:

Use callr to create an R session.
Copy the generated function g() to the global environment of this R session.
Call j() in this R session and get the results.

# In my case, j() is exported from a package
j <- function(g_name) {
    out <- h(g_name = g_name)
    cat("The body of `out`\n")
    print(body(out))
    cat("Call out:\n")
    out()
  }

# In my case, h() is an internal function
# of a package, called by j()
h <- function(g_name) {
    out <- function() NULL
    body_str <- paste0(g_name, "()")
    body(out) <- parse(file = "",
                       text = body_str)
    out
  }

f <- function() {
    on.exit(try(r$close(), silent = TRUE))
    g <- function() {
        10
      }
    r <- callr::r_session$new()
    r$run(function(x) {g <<- x},
           args = list(x = g))
    # If j() and h() are in a package,
    # then no need to do the following assignments.
    r$run(function(x) {j <<- x},
           args = list(x = j))
    r$run(function(x) {h <<- x},
           args = list(x = h))
    # Run the function in the child process
    out <- r$run(function(x) {
                    j(g_name = "g")
                  })
    # If j() is in a package 'pkg', this one
    # should work
    # out <- r$run(function(x) {
    #                 pkg::j(g_name = "g")
    #              })
    r$close()
    out
  }

z <- f()
z
#> [1] 10

Created on 2024-05-24 with reprex v2.1.0
I believe this solution should work if j() and h() are in a package, and only j() is exported. The solution is even simpler in this case because there is no need to copy them to the R session. Just using pkg::h() will work.
This solution has the drawback to create and then terminate an R session, which takes time. Coincidentally, the task I need to do is a time consuming one and the call to j() can take over ten seconds to finish. Therefore, the overhead to create and terminate an R session is not a concern in my case, relative to the time in running j().
I am new to callr. If this solution can be improved, I would love to know.
